# Get a copy of the pointer to an array in c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Hi I am learning C++ Primer and have a simple question. Please help me out.

So I know that "int *p = (*q)[10]" where p is a pointer to an array of 10. The question is, in a function definition: "void print(int (*q)[10])" where this pointer is a parameter. how could I get the copy of that pointer. Will that be "int *p = q"?

I technically don't know how to test my correctness in C++.

Thanks

Comment: Why do not you use `int *p = new int[10]` for initialization array with 10 int values?

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko Because new is bad.

Comment: @NeilKirk Why? Or what do you mean?

Comment: If you use new you have to manage the memory (call delete)

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko There's no need for dynamic allocation when the size is known at compile time, and if it was, `std::vector` should be preferred unless there are special requirements.

Comment: @NeilKirk OK, I understood you. Thanks.

Comment: `int *p = (*q)[10]` This dereferences the pointer `q`, advances 10 positions in memory, expecting something which can become `int *` and stores it in `p`.

Comment: The sentence beginning with "So I know" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yeah I will care for that next time. Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*q)[10]
```

declares `q` as a pointer to array of 10 `int`s. Only arrays decay to pointers to their underlying type, but pointers to arrays **do not decay** to pointers to underlying type, so trying `int* p = q;` will result in a compilation error. What you need is

```
int (*p)[10] = q; // copies the pointer q to p
```

Comment: oic, yeah dat makes sense. Thx! So I guess to access the elements in this array, I can use (*p)[i] right?

Comment: @user3577115 Yes, that's correct. The type of `*p` is array `int[10]`, so `(*p)[i]` (or `*(*p+i)`) is its i-th element.

Comment: I have tried “*(*p+i)” and of course it worked. But as my understanding, "*" has a higher precedence than "+" so "*p + i" is actually an array plus an int? Does it have such overload function?

Comment: `*p` is an array, which, when used as `*p`, decays to a pointer to its underlying type. So `*p + i` is incrementing the pointer `int*`  by `i` elements. It's the same as when you use `int arr[10]; *(arr+i) = 42;` Here `*p` plays the role of `arr`. Only the pointer to array does not decay to a pointer to the underlying type, but the array itself decays to a pointer.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thank you so much for that.